# Bind to only to certain actions in WebsocketBinding

Tags: django-channels

I am developing an application with Django Channels in which I have a model whose changes are automatically published over a WebSocket channel using `WebSocketBinding`. In this particular case, only the `create` and `delete` messages are relevant, and as such, I thought it might be better if the `update` messages were never sent, instead of ignoring them completely in the frontend part of the setup. I have tried overriding the different handlers in the base `Binding` class of channels (`post_save_receiver`, `pre_save_receiver` and the like), as well as extending that class and `WebsocketBinding` to no avail. My question is: is there a simple way of achieving this? In the documentation I could not find any pointers. If not, what would be the simplest way to get it done?

Thanks in advance!